# Why Python's namedtuple instance is being created from a string template?

Tags: python, python-2.7, collections, namedtuple

While I was reading the source of Python's `collections` module (http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/collections.py#l234), I found that `namedtuple` function creates the definition of a class from a string template which is executed with `exec`. Why isn't it done by simply defining a class inside the function, like you do it when you write a decorator? It seems to me that it would be more readable and more reliable solution, wouldn't it? I bet Python core developers know what they do, so what am I missing here?

Comment: What is your metric on readable and reliable?  The string template certainly reads like a class, and reliability should have been proven with unit testing.

Comment: My metric is common sense and generally accepted standards. Following the example of this part of `collections`, we could put any piece of code inside a string and call it with `exec`. While using a regular class definition (plus introspection) might be considered as "a little bit of magic", the template solution looks more like a dirty hack. However I'm not arguing that this is not the best solution - this is why I asked this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raymond Hettinger mentions this briefly in his [original ActiveState recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/500261-named-tuples/):

> Thanks to Peter Kovac pointing-out deficiencies in the keyword
>   argument checking. Because of his comments, the recipe has evolved to
>   its current exec-style where we get all of Python's high-speed builtin
>   argument checking for free. The new style of building and exec-ing a
>   template made both the `__new__` and `__repr__` functions faster and
>   cleaner than in previous versions of this recipe.

Comment: This is much more comprehensive explanation, as it points motives behind this approach. Thank you, Sir!